# Angular 10/Typescript: What is the difference between how the same property of an object is being assigned

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object Person being passed on from a parent component as shown below. The name is initialized to an empty string when declaring the property before ngOnInit(). The property is used to set a boolean in another component. Even though the parent component has a value of name = John in the parent component, scenario 1 wipes that value out to an empty string thus affecting the boolean. Scenario 2 does not alter the value of name = John. What is the difference between the two assignments in scenario 1 and 2? and why is scenario 1 wiping out the original value in the parent component?

```
export interface IPerson {
 name?: string;
}

// In a child component:
@Input() person: IPerson = { name: '' }

// scenario 1:
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.person.name = '';

}

// scenario 2:
ngOnInit(): void {
this.person = { name: '' }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this becomes more clear if you use a distinct value instead of an empty string. Say we have the same setup:

```js
export interface IPerson {
    name?: string
}

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-parent', 
  template: `
    <p>Parent value: {{person.name}}</p>
    <app-child [person]="person"></app-child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
  person: IPerson = { name: 'John' };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>Child value: {{person.name}}</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() person: IPerson = { name: '' };

  ngOnInit() {
    // Scenario 1:
    this.person.name = 'Felicity';
    // Scenario 2:
    this.person = { name: 'Norah' };
  }
}
```

When you render the parent component, you'll see something similar to this:

```
Parent value: Felicity
Child value: Norah
```

This is because in scenario 1, we have changed the `name` field on the parent's object. It was passed "by reference" if you will, so modifications on the field have changed what the parent knows.

Scenario 2 has forgotten about the object from the parent and replaced it with a new object that only the child knows about. Hence we see two different names; one in the parent and one in the child.

Play around with it using this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z62roa?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.ts).

---

In your case, scenario 1 overwrites "John" because you're changing the actual object passed from the parent. Scenario 2 does not overwrite "John" because you're working with a new object, not the one passed from the parent.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation DM!